# MySQL cmd line characters

Tags: mysql, bash, command-line

I'm trying to remove stray characters that ended up in a MySQL table. So to remove `_`, I just did this:

`UPDATE table SET field = REPLACE(field, '_', '');`

Now I'm trying to do the same thing with `¬`, but I can't place this character in the command line (bash). Any tips for encoding / escaping this character?

Comment: try hitting ctrl-V first before pasting in the character. That's an escape sequence for most shell's command lines.

Comment: Escaping with `\ ` doesn't work -- it doesn't even let me paste the character in. Ctrl-V doesn't seem to do anything (I'm using Mac OS X terminal, if that makes a difference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your locale, but if you're using UTF-8 then this works for me:

echo -e  '\0302\0254'

Update:

Does this do it for you?

```
mysql> select x'c2ac';
+---------+
| x'c2ac' |
+---------+
| ¬      |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works in the shell, but not the MySQL command. The db table is utf8.